# Setting three sided border for UITableView - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitableview

For my design specifications, my table view should only have three borders on top, left, and right. I have added it using the following code....

```
CGSize mainViewSize = menu_table.bounds.size;
CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, borderWidth, mainViewSize.height)];
UIView *rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(mainViewSize.width - borderWidth, 0, borderWidth, mainViewSize.height)];
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainViewSize.width, borderWidth)];
leftView.opaque = YES;
rightView.opaque = YES;
topView.opaque = YES;
leftView.backgroundColor = borderColor;
rightView.backgroundColor = borderColor;
topView.backgroundColor = borderColor;

// for bonus points, set the views' autoresizing mask so they'll stay with the edges:
leftView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
rightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
topView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

[menu_table addSubview:leftView];
[menu_table addSubview:rightView];
[menu_table addSubview:topView];
```

It is working fine, But when I scroll the table, subviews added also moving up. I am not sure why subviews are moving with cells instead it should fix with table, Any idea what is the problem and how to fix it with table view size. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much in detail, but an easiest way I can think of is add 3 contentviews in your tableview like below:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //add left view
    UIView *vwLeft=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_POS, Y_POS, LINE_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT)];
    [vwLeft setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:vwLeft];
    [vwLeft release];

     //add right view
    UIView *vwRight=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_POS, Y_POS, LINE_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT)];
    [vwRight setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:vwRight];
    [vwRight release];

    //add top view
    UIView *vwTop=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_POS, Y_POS, LINE_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT)];
    [vwTop setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:vwTop];
    [vwTop release];

}
return cell;
```

}

Enjoy Programming !

Comment: I have tried, problem now is I have kept some image at bottom of table, If I scroll up, once the rows moved up empty spaces in table don't have borders and it is not touching that image as it is  done have cells. Looking odd.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot for it!